# org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected

Tags: apache, http, rest-assured, chunked-encoding, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying out RestAssured & wrote the following statements -

```
String URL = "http://XXXXXXXX";
Response result = given().
            header("Authorization","Basic xxxx").
            contentType("application/json").
            when().
            get(url);
JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(result.asString());
```

On the last statement, I am receiving the following exception :

`org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected`

The headers returned in my response are :

`Content-Type → application/json; qs=1
Date → Tue, 10 Nov 2015 02:58:47 GMT
Transfer-Encoding → chunked`

Could anyone guide me on resolving this exception & point me out if I am missing anything or any in-correct implementation.

Comment: Which version of rest-assured do you use?

Comment: I was using an older version of RestAssured & now tried with 2.4.1 version & it seems to work. Thanks @fiddler for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue that wasn't related to [rest-assured](/questions/tagged/rest-assured), but this was the first result Google found so I'm posting my answer here, in case others face the same issue.

For me, the problem was (as `ConnectionClosedException` clearly states) `closing` the connection before reading the response. Something along the lines of:

```java
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

try {
    doSomthing();
} finally {
    response.close();
}
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream instream = entity.getContent(); // Response already closed. This won't work!
```

The Fix is obvious. Arrange the code so that the response isn't used after closing it:

```java
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

try {
    doSomthing();
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent(); // OK
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try fiddling around with the [connection config](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#connection-config)? For example:

```
given().config(RestAssured.config().connectionConfig(connectionConfig().closeIdleConnectionsAfterEachResponse())). ..
```